# Windows PATH - why are variables being permanently expanded

Tags: windows, path, expand

I am not new to the PATH statement or DOS and I know how the variable substitution works.  I am experiencing unexpected behavior only one one computer.  All are using Windows 7 x64 or Windows 2008 x64 Server R2.

On all systems, the PATH contains other environment variables.  This works as I expect it to.  However, on one Windows 7 Enterprise, the PATH statement gets changed to permanent expand the variables.  Here is an example, from :

This works on all system except one:

> System variables
>
> ```
> ANT_HOME=C:\dev\ant
> JAVA_HOME=C:\dev\java
> MAVEN_HOME=C:\dev\maven
> PATH=[standard Windows paths go here];%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
> ```

One one system, when I make the change to the PATH variable on the Environment Variables window, it eventually gets changed to the fully expanded values.  I am not referring to when running within a DOS prompt, I am referring to the location in Windows where these settings are changed.

I have not been able to figure out what is causing this to change.  It makes it impossible to easily switch one of the XXX_HOME values to a different version and expect the PATH to receive the updates.  If this is the way Windows always worked, I would understand, but why on only one system?

Does anything have any ideas or what is causing this?  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: There is probably some third-party software running on the system in question that is messing with the path.  Have you checked for any applications that are only installed on this one system and not on the others?

Comment: Harry -Yes I have.  I suspected it was CCleaner, but after resetting the path (again!) and forcing it to run (there is an option in there for cleaning up the PATH variable), it was still OK.  This does seem to be my last resort -- which is to keep checking every few hours and wait for it to get modified.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could leave Process Monitor (available from MS website) running, looking for writes to the Environment key.  That should tell you which executable is responsible for the change.